# How can I convert md to pdf with pictures in and handle the error 'Could not find image..'?

Tags: diagrams

I want to use pandoc to convert md format document into pdf format,latex template has been written, and example content which will be converted as follows(named as "example.md"):

```
picture one:
![1](../images/1/1.1.png?raw=true)
picture two:
![2](../images/1/1.2.png?raw=true)
```

And the two pictures '1.1.1.png' and '1.2.png' are in 'images',
use win7 cmd as follows:

```
pandoc  --latex-engine=xelatex  --template=latex.template.tex example.md -o example.pdf
```

But results display error:

```
pandoc: Could not find image '../images/1/1.1.png?raw=true', skipping...
pandoc: Could not find image '../images/1/1.2.png?raw=true', skipping...
pandoc: Error producing PDF from Tex source.
!Unable to load picture or PDF file '../images/1/1.1.png?raw=true'
<to be read again>
                  }
1.172 ...yu/1.1.png?raw=true}
```

So what's the matter with the error, and the pictures are exactly existing in 'images', How can I handle the error? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might need to remove `?raw=true`—that's web-specific

Comment: Thank you! Yes,it's ok now by deleting     ?raw=true

Answer (score 1):

Delete `?raw=true` from the file path.
Web stuff often has parameters that forms `POST`
  to send extra information to the server in order to get what you want.
Your filesystem doesn't have such a feature,
  so the error is thrown.
It is looking for a file that is literally called

```
1.1.png?raw=true
```

where the file on your system is simply

```
1.1.png
```